# SQL query to delete databases with specific string

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I know this has been asked in some contexts but I cannot follow how they are working. If there are plenty of useful answers to this question then just down vote me but please link the relevant questions before you do. 

I am trying to write a query that will run in a batch file to automatically delete tables that have a specific string in their name. For example, when I run the batch file, I want it to look for tables that might have a ABCDir in the file. I have tried some various ways to get this to work with no success yet.

I know this is close to what I'm trying to do. Or I guess it could be way off lol.

```
DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR
DELETE name FROM sys.database
WHERE name LIKE '%ABCDir%'
```

Comment: Do you want to delete the contents of the table or drop the table? The example posted by Raj Moore will drop the tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Warning** This is a very dangerous practice.  Consider renaming the tables instead of delete.

**Answer**

You will have to create Dynamic SQL as an example of how to drop tables (I just couldn't bring myself to write `DROP DATABASE`)

```
Declare @strSQL nVarChar (Max) = ';
'

select @strSQL = @strSQL  + 'Drop Table ' + T.TABLE_SCHEMA + '.'+ TABLE_NAME + ';
'
From INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES   T
Where Table_Name Like '%ABC1234%'

Print @strSQL
Exec Sp_ExecuteSQL @strSQL
```

Comment: I hope you'll forgive my ignorance, I'm new to SQL. Does this query work for any database or do I need to put relevant information in the TABLE_SCHEMA and TABLE_NAME spots?

Comment: This would work for any databases that you have permissions to.

Comment: Best use QUOTENAME for the schema and table name, you never know if there's any names with spaces or other special characters in them.